# Using complete() with ggplot causes bars to appear up to 5 counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making side-by-side bar plots with `ggplot`, and since I want there to be consistent positioning for each bar even when there are missing values, I'm using the `complete()` function and the argument `position_dodge(preserve = "single")`. However, rather than just having blank space where the missing values would go, I'm instead seeing small bars. Here's some minimal code to reproduce the effect:

```
data <- data.frame("col1" = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "a", "c"),
                   "col2" = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"))

data %>%
  complete(col1, col2) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = col2)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = col1),
             position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Bar plot]

The counts for `x>b`, `x>c`, and `y>a` are all zero, but there are bars present that make them look like they're all counts of 1. How do I stop these bars from appearing?

Comment: `geom_bar` counts observations (cases in the online doc), so what you are seeing is expected because of your use of `complete`.  Perhaps you need `geom_col()`?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment,

```
data %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  summarise(N = n(), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  complete(col1, col2, fill=list(N = 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = col2, y = N)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(fill = col1),
    position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")
  )
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Limey’s solution, but using `dplyr::count()` with `.drop = FALSE` rather than `summarize()` and `complete()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  count(col2, col1 = factor(col1), .drop = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = col2, y = n)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = col1), position = "dodge")
```

[image]